# Linear Morphism between Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have a question concerning a construction introduced in Bosch's "Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra" ( pages 428/ 429). Here the relevant excerpt:

[image]

We start with a scheme $\mathbb{A}^1 _U = \mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} \times_{\mathbb{Z}} U$ over a base scheme $U$.

Then we define a morphism $\psi: \mathbb{A}^1 _U \to \mathbb{A}^1 _U $ via

$$(t,x) \mapsto (\eta(x) \cdot t, x)$$

for a section $\eta \in \mathcal{O}_U(U)$, $t \in \mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}}, x \in U$.

What I don't understand what is concretely $\eta(x) \cdot t$, how the multiplication "$\cdot$" on $t$ is defined and why set theoretically $\eta(x) \cdot t \in \mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}}$?

Below it is explained how $\psi$ is defined on level of rings namely as a map of ringed spaces we have by definition for an open affine subset $Spec(R)= V \subset U$ the description as ring map

$$\psi^{\#} _{\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} \times V}: R[\zeta]=\mathbb{A}^1 _U(\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} \times V) \to \mathbb{A}^1 _U(\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} \times V)$$

$$\zeta \mapsto (\eta \vert _{Spec(R)}) \cdot \zeta$$

Take into account that $\mathbb{A}^1 _U(\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} \times V)= \mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} ) \otimes _{\mathbb{Z}} R = R[\zeta]$.

So on level of local sections the definition of $\psi$ is clear.

What I don't understand how to interpret $(t,x) \mapsto (\eta(x) \cdot t, x)$ on level of Specs. Indeed, $t \in \mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}}, x \in U$. What is $\eta(x) \cdot t$?

Set theoretically since $\mathbb{A}^1 _U = \mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}} \times_{\mathbb{Z}} U$ the $\eta(x) \cdot t$ lives in first factor $\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}}$.

But how $\eta(x) \cdot$ "acts" on $t$? Can $\eta(x)$ be interpreted as an element in residue field $\mathcal{O}_{U, x}/m_x= \kappa(x)$? If yes, then the prime ideal $\eta(x) \cdot t$ doesn't live in $\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Z}}$.

So what is strictly speaking the object $\eta(x) \cdot t$?

Answer (score 0):

A regular function is the same thing as a map to $\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Z}$, so $\eta(x)$ really does live on $\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Z}$. It's good to think about why this should be.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. I know how a regular function is defined as a morphism between varieties (namely locally by polynomials) but I don't know how to interpret $\eta$ as a regular function for schemes. What is the domain and codomain? I guess you mean that in the sense $\eta: U \to \mathbb{A}^1_Z, x \mapsto \eta(x)$, right? 
But what concretely does is $\eta(x)$? And what is the "multiplication" $\eta(x) \cdot t$? Set theoretically it seems to be an operation $\mathbb{A}^1_Z \times \mathbb{A}^1_Z \to \mathbb{A}^1_Z$ on level on Specs. I don't see it's meaning.

Comment: I tried to think a bit about your argument concerning interpretation of $\eta$ as regular function. Intuitively $\eta \in \mathcal{O}_U(U)$ provides following map: $\eta: U \to \coprod_{x \in X}\kappa(x), x \mapsto \kappa(x) = \mathcal{O}_{U,x}/p_x$ where $p_x$ is the prime ideal of an affine neighbourhood of $x$. I still don't understand two points:

How this construction provide a map $\eta$ to $\mathbb{A}^1_Z$ and what is $\eta(x) \cdot t$ as multiplication in $\mathbb{A}^1_Z$?

Comment: UPDATE: the question why $\eta$ maps to $\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Z}$ is solved now so we have indeed $\eta(x) \in \mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Z}$. The only problem staying unsolved is the meaning of the "multiplication" in $\eta(x) \cdot t$. Do we implicitely enrich implicitely $\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Z}$ with a structure of a group scheme? Or does it have another meaning?

Comment: I quite uncertain if that is ***the*** action I meant in my last comment. I thoutht that the "." in $\eta(x) \cdot t$ has to be settled by a map/operation $m:\mathbb{A}^1_Z \times \mathbb{A}^1_Z \to \mathbb{A}^1_Z, (t,r) \mapsto t \cdot r$. I have no idea what $m$ is. The comment from my last post with group action was just a vague suggestion. If - then we have to talk about group scheme structure on $\mathbb{A}^1_Z$. There exist on $\mathbb{A}^1_Z$ an additive group structure but I'm not sure if it here meant by "."